# How to grep to (not) match the special character "/" (no quotes) at the end each line

Tags: unix, search, grep, special-characters

I want to grep through a large file for lines not ending in "/" (no quotes). Here is a sample file:

```
Folder1/clicker7Mac/
Folder1/clicker7Mac/clicker7.17.0_Mac/Resources/
Folder2/
Folder2/file of interest1.pdf
Folder2/Grades/
Folder2/Grades/another file of interest.pdf
Folder2/Grades/other files with unknown but not-slash extension
Folder2/Final_exam/
Folder2/Final_exam/a 3rd file.pdf
Folder2/Grades/an excel file of interest.xlsx
Folder2/Grades/Package_for_someone/
Folder2/HW/
Folder2/HW/HW1/
```

I want only the lines ending in files, not the lines that are directory paths. I.e. here I want output:

```
Folder2/file of interest1.pdf
Folder2/Grades/another file of interest.pdf
Folder2/Grades/other files with unknown but not-slash extension
Folder2/Final_exam/a 3rd file.pdf
Folder2/Grades/an excel file of interest.xlsx
```

I've searched stack exchange and unix forums and have tried the following (note I have inverted the search because it's easier to test):

```
grep  '.*/' testfile
grep  '\w*/\b' testfile
```

(greps all words and slashes, takes files as well; grep -v yeilds nothing)

```
grep  "[a-z.0-9]"'/\b' testfile
```

(last character before all slashes; grep -v yeilds nothing)

```
grep  '\l*/\b' testfile
grep  '\>/' testfile
```

(all slashes (not just the end slash); grep -v yeilds nothing)

```
grep -F  '/\b' testfile
```

(fgrep or grep -F treats as literal string and yeilds nothing; grep -v yeilds everything)

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -v '/$' file
```

or

```
grep '[^/]$' file
```

Output:

```
Folder2/file of interest1.pdf
Folder2/Grades/another file of interest.pdf
Folder2/Grades/other files with unknown but not-slash extension
Folder2/Final_exam/a 3rd file.pdf
Folder2/Grades/an excel file of interest.xlsx
```

---

See: `man grep` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Yes, thanks- that does it! I obviously didn't know about the end-of-line "$" flag, so thanks for the link to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -v` to exclude all lines that end with `/`:

```
$ grep -v '/$' testfile
Folder2/file of interest1.pdf
Folder2/Grades/another file of interest.pdf
Folder2/Grades/other files with unknown but not-slash extension
Folder2/Final_exam/a 3rd file.pdf
Folder2/Grades/an excel file of interest.xlsx
```

`-v` is portable and specified by [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/grep.html).

Comment: yes thanks that works, it was the "$" end-of-line flag that I didn't know. I'll need to read up more on regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is an option:

```
awk -F'/' '$NF' file
Folder2/file of interest1.pdf
Folder2/Grades/another file of interest.pdf
Folder2/Grades/other files with unknown but not-slash extension
Folder2/Final_exam/a 3rd file.pdf
Folder2/Grades/an excel file of interest.xlsx
```

It sets the Field Separator to `/` and then test if last field contains some thing and then do default action, print the line.

Another variation more like the `grep` solution, test if line does not end with `/`:

```
awk '!/[/]$/' file
Folder2/file of interest1.pdf
Folder2/Grades/another file of interest.pdf
Folder2/Grades/other files with unknown but not-slash extension
Folder2/Final_exam/a 3rd file.pdf
Folder2/Grades/an excel file of interest.xlsx
```